# Правописание с "двух-" и "дву-"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, словообразование, сложные-слова

Как правильно писать слова:
*двухдневный (двудневный), двухразовый, двухзначный (двузначный)*?
Где найти такое правило?

Answer (score 3):

В словаре только. 
Правил как таковых нет, есть некоторые статистические закономерности. Научный язык обычно тяготеет к "дву-", бытовой - к "двух". Но это не абсолютно.
А вообще большинство слов допускает обаварианта, но есть некотрые устоявшиеся термины.

Все ваши варианты допустимы.